# set greater / set to greater/set to a value greater

Tags: verbs

> For correct printing, the bottom margin should be set **greater** than 1cm.

I drafted this sentence.  When I googled this by replacing "**greater**" with **"to greater"** and "**to a value greater**", some examples were hit. I would like to know which is the best.

Comment: ....should be set larger/higher than 1 cm.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner isn't '_greater_' correct too?

Answer (score 2):

For the readers' sake, you can and should probably use the shorter and simpler sentence

> For correct printing, the bottom margin should be greater than 1 cm.

People will understand that they should *set* something in order to make it happen.

Comment: I agree with you, but I would like to know the correct usage when "set" is used.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "**set greater than**" ([**Google search**](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GKLB_ruRU733RU733&q=%22be%20set%20greater%20than%22&oq=%22be%20set%20greater%20than%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...26562.28617.0.29364.3.3.0.0.0.0.94.249.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.174...0i8i30k1.0.bSDonb9lbvM)). However, if you wish to use a proper construction then use "**set to a value greater than**" *(more common - [**Google search**](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GKLB_ruRU733RU733&q=%22be%20set%20to%20a%20value%20greater%20than%22&oq=%22be%20set%20to%20a%20value%20greater%20than%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...30404.32294.0.34037.11.11.0.0.0.0.94.889.11.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.l8zBWdoqOW8))* or "**set to a greater value than**" *(less common - [**Google search**](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GKLB_ruRU733RU733&q=%22be%20set%20to%20a%20greater%20value%20than%22&oq=%22be%20set%20to%20a%20greater%20value%20than%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...107390.109517.0.110566.7.7.0.0.0.0.94.578.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.uGgOl3eJpXA))*. These both being more the kind of writing used in manuals and documents.